# Error: 1146 - Table 'X' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

Three years ago I exported an SQL database for a forum of mine and evidently my hosting servers crapped out mid-export and all tables from the letter "S" to the letter "Z" were never exported. I was not aware of this because phpMyAdmin never gave me an error and so I zipped that export, stashed it on a backup drive and hadn't touched it until today.

This forum happens to have tens of thousands of posts. I'd like to recover this archive if at all possible, even if that means whatever database tables went missing means missing data -- I just want the posts for my players to be able to reflect on. I've reached out to the forum developer but they kicked me back to my web host, stating that corrupt SQL files is outside their scope of support. $175 for a license and *that's* the support I get. My web host sent me here.

That said, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: 1146 - Table 'X.sessions' doesn't exist
```

"X" is the name of my database, so that's been edited for privacy concerns.

This also displays (not sure if it's relevant):

```
mySQL query error: DELETE FROM sessions WHERE ip_address= 'X'
```

Again, "X" is my IP address.

Is there any query that I can run to manually insert missing tables as I see them listed in the error log, even if just to get the site to load? What other options are available to me? Thank you.

Comment: which RDBMS here, mysql or sql-server? 2 different animals here. and what's the real/full query?

Comment: you only seem to be responding to answers then. I revisited this question by pure courtesy, yet you're not telling us which RDBMS you're using as I asked you already and as to what the full query was, so you'll just have to keep up with the answer given below, good luck, I have left this one for good.

Answer (score 0):

First, just adding the tables back is not going to help.  Each table consists of a definition of different columns (like for a thread, it would be thread id, thread title, thread post date, etc, etc).  Just creating tables with nothing in them will not make the forum work any better than it does now.

A bigger issue, is that since there doesn't seem to be a prefix on the table names (evident from the name 'sessions'), then you are probably missing your "Threads" table as well.  The threads are the conversations, and usually contain many posts.  Without your threads table, there is no way for your software to organize the posts.

To sum up, you're not going to be able to bring back up the forum with just a partial database.  There's a couple of things you could try with the data that you have (like building something to just list the posts, grouped by threadid) but it's not going to give you what you're asking for.

Comment: You've provided more information than I've found in 12+ hours of talks with the forum devs, my web host, and scouring Google results.

Could you point me to information on displaying that data as you mentioned? As it stands now, the forum doesn't load at all.

Comment: There is nowhere for me to point you, a custom php script would need to be written that does a query on your posts, groups them by thread id, sorts by date/time ascending and displays them inline.  This would definitely just be a way to let your users see the data, but would require someone with php experience to get it done.

Comment: I appreciate the responses thus far. I copy/pasted the missing tables from another SQL database and was able to get the forum online. A good portion of the content is viewable (not sure how) but that'll do for now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you were able to find a way to create the missing tables.